# Next.js not updating state during OnClick after router.push to same page with different ID

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a page similar to this:

File: `[pid].tsx`

```
type ProblemPageProps = {
    problem: Problem
};

const ProblemPage:React.FC<ProblemPageProps> = ({problem}) => {
    ...

    return (
        <div>
            <Workspace problem={problem} />
        </div>
    );
}
export default ProblemPage;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = Object.keys(problems).map((key) => ({
        params: {pid:key}
    }))

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps({params}: {params: {pid: string}}) {
    const {pid} = params;
    const problem = problems[pid];

    if (!problem) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    }

    return {
        props: {
            problem
        }
    }
}
```

In `Workspace` I have something like this - gets triggered on a click of a button:

```
const handleCodeReset = () => {
    setUserCode(problem.starterCode);
};
```

And I have one function to push to the **same** `[pid].tsx` page but with a different PID:

```
const handlePreviousProblemChange = () => {
    router.push(`/problems/my_second_problem`);
}
```

Being triggered by:

```
<div onClick={() => handlePreviousProblemChange()}>
    BLA BLA BLA
</div>
```

When that happens, `problem` is pointing to `my_second_problem` which is exactly what I need but during `onClick` event, `problem.starterCode` still points to the previous `pid`. What can I do to make sure `problem.startedCode` gets referenced in the right way?

This is an example of `problem`:

```
interface ProblemMap {
    [key: string]: Problem;
}

export const problems: ProblemMap = {
    "key": value,
    ...
}
```